# Sentence classification using Weka

Tags: machine-learning, classification, weka

I want to classify sentences with Weka. My features are sentence terms (words) and a Part of Speech tag of each terms. I don't know how figure attributes, because if each term is presented as one feature, number of feature for each instance (sentence) has become different. And, if all words in sentence is presented as one feature, how relate words and their POS tag.

Any ideas how I should proceed?

Comment: As input you have a sentence with its word and POS tags, but what do you want as output? Simple binary classification where given a sentence the output is `True` or or `False`? Or do you have multiple labels (e.g, categories which you want to classify the sentences with)?

Comment: it is a simple binary classification problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, the answer is as follows: It is most common to treat words independently of their position in the sentence and represent a sentence in the feature space by the number of times each of the known words occurs in that sentence. I.e. there is usually a separate numerical feature for each word present in the training data. Or, if you're willing to use n-grams, a separate feature for every n-gram in the training data (possibly with some frequency threshold).

As for the POS tags, it might make sense to use them as separate features, but only if the classification you're interested in has to do with sentence structure (syntax). Otherwise you might want to just append the POS tag to the word, which would partly disambiguate those words that can represent different parts of speech.